# Visual SVN/Tortoise 'Delete - keep local' problem

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I wanted to remove some files from the repository (while leaving them locally), and stop tracking them in the future.

I tried this:
- Used Tortoise 'Delete - Keep local' on the directory I wanted to remove from versioning.
- Comitted to the repository.

This commit failed with this error: `commit failed... item is out of date`

Can anyone tell me

**a) What the correct procedure is for this?**

**b) What can I do to get back to a working repository?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to first run `svn update` before you commit your changes. Then you can run `svn del <file>` to remove the files. Then try your commit again.

Comment: Ok, I ran update, then 'svn delete' on the folder in question, and tried to commit again.  The commit failed with the following error: Aborting commit: 'xxxx' remains in conflict.  Any ideas?

Comment: I ran 'svn resolve' on the folder, and it seems to be ok now.  Can anyone tell me what the propper process is in the future for removing items from versioning with tortoise? (e.g. obj and bin folders).

Comment: Update - it seems that the above deleted the local directory, which I didn't want to do.